# Handling local types name collision with global native types

Tags: typescript

Say I want to define types / interfaces like `Node`, `ChildNode`. Both of these are in the global DOM types. If I define them or import them, my local types will override the native types - as intended. But what if I want to use the native type in a file that uses my custom type? Is it possible to add some namespace or import the native type with a different name so they can coexist?

Comment: You could alias your custom type in files where you also want to use your custom types, e.g. `import { Node as MyNode } from '...'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alias to a native type can be created by declaring it in the global namespace.

`global.ts` (a file present in the path of`typeRoots` of `tsconfig.json`)

```
declare global {
  type DOMNode = Node;
  type DOMChildNode = ChildNode;
}
```

This makes `DOMNode` and `DOMChildNode` globally available as aliases of `Node` and `ChildNode` respectively. That means I can define my own type `ChildNode` and be able to use the DOM type in the same file with `DOMChildNode`.

```
type ChildNode = { /* ... */ }

let myNode: ChildNode;
let domNode: DOMChildNode;
```

This can also be implemented with a local import

```
export type DOMNode = Node;
export type DOMChildNode = ChildNode;
```

```
import type { DOMNode } from './types';
```